# how can i print pass if there's no diff when using difflib.unified_diff

Tags: python, list, file, encoding, compare

this code will comapre before and after using difflib and will print the diff, thw question if theres no diff how can i print no diff ?

```
import difflib
before = ['abc\n', 'def\n']
after = ['xyz\n', 'def\n']
for line in difflib.unified_diff(before, after):
   print (line)
```

i tried to wirte it as:

```
import difflib
before = ['abc\n', 'def\n']
after = ['xyz\n', 'def\n']
for line in difflib.unified_diff(before, after):
    x = len(line)
    if x == 0:
        print (line)
    else:
        print("no diff")
```

but its not working !

re witre the code, to print out

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rearrange your logic a little.

Try this,

```
import difflib

before = ['abc\n', 'def\n']
after = ['xyz\n', 'def\n']

diff = list(difflib.unified_diff(before, after))

if len(diff) == 0:
    print("no diff")
else:
    for line in diff:
        print(line)
```

You run the difflib function first and check the length. If it’s zero print no diff, but if it’s not, run the for loop as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ndiff : https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff

Your solution is simple,
After you declare the variable do,

```py
diff = list(difflib.ndiff(before, after)

if not diff:
    print("It doesn't exist")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).